# Editing Flip Card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, blazor

In my Blazor application, I have implemented a card-flip on mouse click. Now I wanted to add the edit functionality, that is as the user clicks on Edit button they enters in edit mode and can edit the card contents directly from the UI. Any lead on how can I achieve it, would be helpful.

Here is the code [BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/mcqa6lo3)

Answer (score 0):

You could start by creating 2 templates for your front and back card layout, one template for Display and one template for Edit, then you could toggle visibility on those templates on an event and copy new values to replace the original ones when the event is fired to exit the Edit template or binding to an object/properties.

Check my take on your code using the binding option.
Also changed the flip event to a double click so you can click the inputs without flipping the card, it's still a little buggy for me, I can only click on the input in some areas of its end, other areas seems like the 'card back' div gets in the way, but I think it's a start so you could try out something on that line of thought and/or fixing those other issues.

https://blazorfiddle.com/s/dvz9ppon

Comment: I have created 2 different templates and thanks for the suggestion of double click, I can proceed further in this way.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! If you're happy with that answer, could you please mark it as best answer?

Comment: Thanks for your help, Could you please suggest me how can I make my content on card editable. I tried using **contenteditable="true"** but couldn't save the changes made. So if you can suggest how can I edit it and save it.

Comment: My blazorfiddle is currently editing and saving, there's an issue to click the edit fields but I think it's related to your card layout.
Try removing the `<div class="card back">` and test the fiddle, you can edit and save using the Edit button to toggle.
I just don't know when the card back div is there, some parts of the inputs aren't clickable, seems like the div is interfering on it.